# Convert array to time series data using DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    id  date        count
0   a   1-Aug-2018  8
1   b   1-Aug-2018  34
2   c   1-Aug-2018  56
3   e   1-Aug-2018  78
4   a   2-Aug-2018  99
5   b   2-Aug-2018  42
6   f   1-Aug-2018  45
7   c   2-Aug-2018  88
8   b   4-Aug-2018  123
9   b   3-Aug-2018  13
10  d   3-Aug-2018  21
11  a   3-Aug-2018  41
```

What I want to achieve is

1. create a column from each unique **date**
2. create a row for each **id**
3. put the **count** values in the corresponding cell

---

```
id  1-Aug-2018  2-Aug-2018  3-Aug-2018  4-Aug-2018
a   8           99          41          -
b   34          42          13          123
c   56          88          -           -
d   -           -           21          -
e   78          -           -           -
f   45          -           -           -
```

Is that possible with pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Use `df = df.pivot('id','date','count')`

Comment: Totally missed that. Thank you for the answer and the link to the duplicate question.